# Cakephp2.5.5: Auth not going to login user

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have created app where I used the AuthComponent for user authentication.

It is working fine.

but I have created one function which login user with user data as follows.

```
protected function __login_user($conditions) {
    $this->User->recursive = -1;
    $userData = $this->User->find('first', array('condtions' => $conditions));
    unset($userData['User']['password']);
    if( !empty( $userData ) ) {
            $this->Auth->login($userData['User']);
            return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This function works fine when I login with ajax.

But if it is http request with post/get it work as::

It redirect me to the login redirect link, show the session for auth too just one time.

When I refresh the page the session get loss and logout.

Does anyone know why this happening?

Comment: Try this `return $this->Auth->login($userData['User']);`.

Comment: Still it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is declared `protected` in php and as it includes at least a preceding underscore character in the name (`_`) it is "private" to cake and can't be [accessed from the outside world](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html#controller-conventions).

Comment: This function just login any user. I am calling it from accessible functions. Like login function is accessible to user. But in some case, say facebook, I fetch the data of user with conditions of facebook id and then login user. This function only return true or false.

Comment: All-though it is protected or private we can access it in same class. I am accessing in same class only.